# pandas: filtering out columns based on total sum and average

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of timeseries data with numerical data in columns.  When plotting this data, I only want to plot certain series that are considered to be insufficient.  Here's how I select which columns to plot:

```
df.loc[:,  (df.iloc[-1] >= 100) & (df.sum() >= 1000)]
```

In other words, the criteria for "significant" is that the total sum of values in a series in over 1000 and the most recent value is at least 100.

This however turned out to be insufficient.  What I need instead is that the sum is over 1000 (as before), but I want the average of the last two rows (the two most recent readings) to be over 100.

How do I change the filter above to compute the average?

In:

```
date           A    B    C   D
2016-04-01    80  235   99   0
2016-04-02    85  295  153  14
2016-04-03   111  363  224  14
2016-04-04   111  379  296  50
2016-04-05    11   51   29   5
```

Out:

```
date           B    C
2016-04-01   235   99
2016-04-02   295  153
2016-04-03   363  224
2016-04-04   379  296
2016-04-05    51   29
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change the slice (`df.iloc[-2:]`) and call `.mean()`:

```
df.loc[:, (df.sum() >= 1000) & (df.iloc[-2:].mean() >= 100)]
```

(There seems to be a mistake in your example. Input and output are different for the last row.)