# How can i make a dataframe where the count is higher than a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

df

```
      a   b   c   d
 0    1   0   0   1
 1    1   1   0   1
 2    0   1   1   1
 3    1   0   0   1
```

I try to get a df where the count of the columns is higher than 2. But can't find the solution for this. It should look like this:

```
     a    d
0    1    1
1    1    1
2    0    1
3    1    1
```

Comment: Use `df.loc[:,df.sum(0).gt(2)]`

Comment: Very similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453385/pandas-filtering-out-columns-based-on-total-sum-and-average

Answer (score 2):

If there are only `1` and `0` values use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), first `:` is for match all rows:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.sum() > 2]
print (df)
   a  d
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  1  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.sum())
a    3
b    2
c    1
d    4
dtype: int64

print (df.sum() > 2)
a     True
b    False
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool
```

If possible another values and need count only `1`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.eq(1).sum() > 2]
```